# How do I inject new manifest into an existing jar for applet

Tags: java, jar, applet, manifest

I have a website that has been working for years (2). But since the new java restrictions (January 2014), my applet is blocked. So after doing some reading, it seems all I have to do is change the manifest file; I don't even need to recompile the code. (If I am wrong about this, please correct me.)

So I have created the following manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_51
Permissions: sandbox
Application-Name: MyFarmingBusiness
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase:http://mycompany.com/version_4/myapplet/
Caller-Allowable-Codebase:www.mycompany.com
Codebase: www.mycompany.com
```

Then to inject the manifest into my jar

- I save the manifest.txt file in the same directory as the jar
- then in mac osx terminal I type: `jar cfm MyGreat.jar manifest.txt

As a result, I get the following error

```
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:410)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:172)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1177)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Another approach might be to recreate the jar anew.
So I did the following

- to extract the source:  `jar xf MyGreat.jar`
- but then, I haven't done this in so long, I don't know how to reconstruct the jar from the source: the source only contains `.class` files in directory `com/mycompany/...` and the manifest in a directory called `META-INF`. I try searching online, but I haven't had much luck on how to do this from terminal.

So maybe someone can tell me how to create a jar with manifest from terminal. I know the command: `jar cvf MyGreat.jar MyGreat`

But how do I get the manifest in? where to I put the manifest with respect to the `.class` files so that in the end, I get a jar file with directories: `com` and `META-INF`

Comment: I assume this jar is unsigned? if so you can just swap the files out with any zip editing tool. the manifest file is in the META-INF directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a <kbd>space</kbd> after the colon. This should work:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_51
Permissions: sandbox
Application-Name: MyFarmingBusiness
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: http://mycompany.com/version_4/myapplet/
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: www.mycompany.com
Codebase: www.mycompany.com
```

Note the additional <kbd>space</kbd> after the **Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase:** and **Caller-Allowable-Codebase:** entry.

According to the [jar file specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Name-Value_pairs_and_Sections), **value** is defined as:

> value:                          SPACE *otherchar newline *continuation

If you add the spaces, it works as expected.

Comment: sure enough the error went away and I was able to create the jar. But when I load the jar on my website, I get dialog: `Application Blocked by Security Settings: Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running`

Comment: @learner Please consider accepting the answer if this was helpful. Regarding the security settings: please post another question, this is something different and posting a new question helps people find it later on.

Comment: I have a bounty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374303/how-do-i-write-a-manifest-file-for-the-new-java-security-barriers